# Calculating value of unique points in polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join, point-in-polygon, within

I'm working with a spatial PostgreSQL database that contains species records, there is a point layer `'spp_points'`, each point has a `"spp_ID"` and `"spp_score"` field. I also have a polygon layer `'field_poly'`.

I need to work out the sum of *unique* `"spp_id"` scores only within each polygon, so multiple records of the same species should only be counted once.

I have tried using the following query but this calculates the total of all species, so multiple instances of the same species are included in the sum:

```sql
SELECT site.gid AS field,
       SUM(spp.total) AS field_score,
       site.geom
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT spp_id,
             spp_score AS total,
             geom
      FROM spp_points) AS spp
JOIN field_poly AS site ON ST_Within(spp.geom, site.geom)
GROUP BY site.gid
```

I'm not sure where I need to go from here.

Comment: Can the same `"spp_ID"` possess a different `"spp_score"`? Or if there are several points with the same `"spp_ID"` they will have the same `"spp_score"`?

Comment: The `"spp_score"` is a value from 1-10, a given `"spp_ID"` will have the same `"spp_score"` so for instance `spp_A` will always have a value of `8`. Note that species with different `"spp_ID"` may have same `"spp_score"` though.

Comment: My understanding is you want for each polygon 1 record for each species? Does the field_poly layer have an ID column?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The field_poly ID column is `"site.gid"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `AVG` of the `spp_points.spp_score` in a sub-query, i.e.

```
SELECT gid,
       SUM(spp_scores) AS field_score
FROM   (
  SELECT ply.gid,
         AVG(pnt.spp_score) AS spp_scores
  FROM   field_poly AS ply
  JOIN   spp_points AS pnt
    ON   ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pnt.geom)
  GROUP BY
         ply.gid, pnt.spp_id
) q
GROUP BY
       gid
;
```

---

This is semantically equal to

```
SELECT gid,
       SUM(spp_score) AS field_score
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (ply.gid, pnt.spp_id, pnt.spp_score)
         ply.gid,
         pnt.spp_id,
         pnt.spp_score
  FROM   field_poly AS ply
  JOIN   spp_points AS pnt
    ON   ST_Intersects(ply.geom, pnt.geom)
) q
GROUP BY
       gid
;
```

However, in cases where `DISTINCT [ON]` is interchangeable with `GROUP BY`, the latter usually outperforms the former.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you're almost there. You just need to also group by `"spp_id"`:

```sql
SELECT data.spp_id,
       SUM(data.spp_score) AS total_score,
       site.gid AS site_id,
       site.geom AS site_geom
FROM spp_points as data
INNER JOIN field_poly AS site ON ST_Within(data.geom, site.geom)
GROUP BY site.gid, site.geom, data.spp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the crux of this problem is in assigning a row_number to all the sightings using the partition on the species ID and the site_gid they are in, and then ordering by the sighting date - which involves using a DATE column - then using only one of each sighting from each polygon.

I've done some mocking up of this using crime and neighborhood data for denver, but re-coded best I could to match your data - my species ID is instead a crime type, and I've used some dummy integer to mock up the spp_score.

Here's the code:

```
;with cte_data as (
select
 f.site_gid
, s.* 
 , row_number() over (partition by s."spp_ID", f.site_gid order by s.sighting_date desc ) as rownum
from spp_points as s 
    join field_poly as f on ST_INtersects(s.geom, f.geom)
)

select 
d.site_gid
, d."spp_ID"
, sum(d.spp_score)
from cte_data as d
where 1=1 and d.rownum = 1
group by d.site_gid, d."spp_ID"
```

Which gives this result, which is one species (crime) per field polygon and sums the spp_score (my dummy offense code integer).

I think its almost what you're after, but let me know what you think.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to get this to work but to no avail. When you talk of the `sighting_date` column, did you create a unique value for each?

Comment: I used a date in the Denver crime dataset... I'm guessing you don't have something similar?