# Selecting more than one point using QGIS

Tags: qgis, select

I am trying to convert the monasteries layers from:
https://harvard-cga.maps.arcgis.com/apps/View/index.html?appid=b4dad589ee4b40e39a93bb0b026e4ee8

into a csv table. For that I am using the WMS link:

https://ags.cga.harvard.edu/arcgis/services/darmc/roman/MapServer/WMSServer

I do that via Layer> add Layer> add WMS/WMTS layer..., then I click new and paster the WMSServer link. I am then able to see all the monastic houses points, so up to here everything all right. Now, comes my problem: Although when I click on one dot I can see the associated info, I don't know how to click more than one spot. I have tried to use the identy features by radius, but then I cannot gather the points.

Comment: WMS GetFeatureInfo request takes image coordinates &i= and &j= as query parameter. It means a single point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way. You can download the entire layer at once, then filter/format it as you wish. Here is the generic solution

1. go to the server URL, in a webbrowser https://ags.cga.harvard.edu/arcgis/rest/services/darmc/roman/MapServer  (note that it is not exactly the URL you have provided
2. click on the layer of interest (note that there are 2 "nonastry" layers), like https://ags.cga.harvard.edu/arcgis/rest/services/darmc/roman/MapServer/35
3. click "query" at the bottom https://ags.cga.harvard.edu/arcgis/rest/services/darmc/roman/MapServer/35/query
4. In the `where` clause, enter `1=1`. A where clause is required but you want all records, so you enter a static expression that will always evaluate to TRUE. In the `Out Fields:` section, enter `*`. At the bottom, in the `format` section, choose `json` (or else). Click the Query button and save the result :-)  (or lazily click [here](https://ags.cga.harvard.edu/arcgis/rest/services/darmc/roman/MapServer/35/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&f=pjson))

Comment: Can you please explain what does this condition `1=1` mean inside `WHERE`, I have seen the same statement here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/376012/99589 ?

Comment: @Taras here, the `where` clause is required. It is evaluated for every row and if the result is `true`, the row is returned, else it is dismissed. In a "normal" sql query, we would simply omit the `where` clause, but since it is required, we want an expression that is always true, and `1=1` is always true

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution worked perfectly!